# VSCode didn't provide autoComplete prompt when entering grey backgroud mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

VSCode didn't provide autoComplete prompt when entering grey backgroud mode.

As you see, there is a grey bar behind the variable "ok_abc".

What's this grey mode and how can I leave this mode?

[image: variable grep bar]

Here is my vscode settings

[image]

I found the cause is ""python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true," There are something wrong with this property.

Comment: What is `/usr/bin/python8`? That may not be working with Jedi appropriately.

Comment: @BrettCannon The python8 is soft link of source compiled python3.8

Comment: @BrettCannon I found the cause is ""python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true," There are something wrong with this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this problem once. The way I solved it was to change the `"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": true,` to `"python.autoComplete.addBrackets": false.`.

However, this may or may not work for you. If you want more info try here(this is where got my solution): https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/452

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you anyway, although I realized the reason before you answer. But why VSCode hasn't fixed this bug?

Comment: I don't know maybe you can raise the issue on github again.